# Why does my parent process also crash after exec()?

Tags: c, fork, exec, clone

I am trying to use clone() to create a child process to exec() some programs. I know that exec() replaces the original process and the process that calls it should end with it, so I use a child process to call exec(). However, for some reasons, after exec(), my parent process crashes also. Could someone tell me why is this happening? (if i replace clone with fork or vfork, it works)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sched.h>

void delNL(char * arry){    //A function to delete the newline at the end of the array
char * position;
position = strchr(arry,'\n');
*position = '\0';
}

int mySysC(char * command){                  //clone funtion
         char *cmd[10]={" "};
        int nb=0;
        int cnb=0;
        while(command[nb]!='\0'){
            char coa[10];
            int cici=0;
            while(command[nb]!=' ' && command[nb]!='\0'){
                coa[cici]=command[nb];
                nb++;
                cici++;
            }
            coa[cici]='\0';
            char *nad=(char *)malloc(10);
            strcpy(nad,coa);
            cmd[cnb]=nad;
            cnb++;
            if(command[nb]==' '){
                nb++;
            }
        }
        cmd[cnb]=NULL;
        execvp(cmd[0],cmd);
        exit(0);
}

void my_system_c(char * command){            //clone version
        void * stack = (void *)malloc(10000);
        void * stackTop = stack + 100000;
        pid_t pid = clone((void *)mySysC(command),stackTop,CLONE_THREAD,NULL);  //clone
    waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
}


int main(){
    char commdd[100];    
    char ex[10]="os_exit";
    while(1){
        printf("Please enter your command or enter \"os_exit\" to exit:\n");
        fgets(commdd,100,stdin);
        delNL(commdd);
        if(strlen(commdd)>0 && strcmp(commdd,ex)!=0){
            my_system_c(commdd);                       //select version
        }
        else if(strcmp(commdd,ex)==0) break;
        else printf("Empty command\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

execvp(cmd[0],cmd); this is what crashed the whole program. I add two prints one before and one after, the later one never runs. I don't understand because of I thought clone works just like fork, which creates a new process, and the end of the chile process won't affect the parent?

Thanks!!!

Comment: strongly suggest: 1) enable the warnings when compiling, then fix those warnings.  2) read/understand the MAN page for `clone()`

Comment: And also read the man page for `strchr()`

Comment: Don't use [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html). Leave it to gurus *implementing* [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html). You are not one yet! Use [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) to create a process, and [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) to create a posix thread

Answer (score 2):

`clone(…CLONE_THREAD…)` is not the `clone()` you're looking for. It creates a new process in the same thread group as the parent process, and:

> If any of the threads in a thread group performs an `execve(2)`, then all threads other than the thread group leader are terminated, and the new program is executed in the thread group leader.

If you are looking for a way to start a process without using `fork()`, consider using [`posix_spawn()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn) instead.

Additionally, the stack pointer you are passing to `clone()` is invalid. The stack you allocate is 10,000 bytes large, but the stack pointer is 100,000 bytes beyond the start of the stack -- and 90,000 bytes  beyond its end.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you never actually call `clone`. This part:

```
clone((void *)mySysC(command), ...);
```

is equivalent to:

```
int result = mSysC(command);
void* first = (void*) result;
clone(first, ...);
```

so it calls your function before it ever calls clone. You need to pass it as a function pointer instead.

In addition to that, you should remove one zero from your `stackTop` to match the malloc, and avoid passing `CLONE_THREAD` since you want a new process:

```
void my_system_c(char * command){            //clone version
  void * stack = (void *)malloc(10000);
  void * stackTop = stack + 10000;
  pid_t pid = clone(mySysC,stackTop,0,command);  //clone
  waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
}
```